# Qt QTcpSocket : unable to receive data

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to send and receive data between 2 applications i.e App1 and app2 where app1 is server and app2 is client/ Socket 
App 2 main work is to do image processing using opencv(like background subtraction, Contours etc..) based on the server(i.e app1) commands and send the contour x,y data back to app1.
This accessing camera and processing is done in a separate thread as camera is running at 120fps and lot of image processing techniques to be performed

```
mywidget::mywidget(int args, char *argv[], QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::mywidget)
{
.... // Other DB coding etc..
Camera = new AccessCamera();
    CameraThread = new QThread();
    Camera->moveToThread(CameraThread);
    CameraThread->start();
    connect(Camera,SIGNAL(EMIT_Camera_Image(cv::Mat,quint64)),this,SLOT(On_Camera_Image(cv::Mat,quint64)));
    connect(Camera,SIGNAL(EMIT_Debug_Messgaes(QString,int)),this,SLOT(on_Camera_Debug_Msg(QString,int)));
.... // Other Coding etc...
// here _socket is object of QTcpSocket
        _socket.connectToHost(QHostAddress(HostAddress),PortNumber);
        connect(&_socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(onReadyRead()));
        connect(&_socket,SIGNAL(connected()),this,SLOT(On_Connected()));
        connect(&_socket,SIGNAL(disconnected()),this,SLOT(On_DisConnected()));
...
}
```

when i try to communicate between app1 and app2 it communicates well but when i send a camera start command from app1 to app2 and when camera starts , app2 doesnt receive any data from there on but when i manually stop camera using GUI push button and then when i send some data from app1 then all the data which failed to come to app2 till that time comes all at once 
for example if i send "stop" command 3 times from app1 and then manually stop camera in app2 and then if i send stop again from app1 it ends up getting "stopstopstopstop" all at once. what is making this problem to occur. I tried to push the QTcpSocket object to QThread i.e
        socThread= new QThread(this);
        _socket.moveToThread(socThread);
this also doesnt work.
By the way this app1 is in master pc and app2 is in slave pc i.e this is between 2 different pcs.
Whats the better way of dealing with QTcpSocket while doing heavy image processing applications or whats the better way to solve this problem. & Where & what am i missing.
Sorry for not sharing the entire coding wrt security concerns & and lot of code dependency.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apps works on OS-Windows? If yeap just try to turn off windows firewall or add your apps in it!

Comment: yes am running on windows 10 pro.I have tried by adding my app in firewall and even tried Turing off the firewalls but still am facing the same problem.